# Migrating Windows 8.1 from a 500GB hard disk to a 4TB hard disk

Tags: windows, hard-drive

How do one migrate Windows 8.1 from a 500GB hard disk to a 4TB hard disk (or to a bigger hard disk) without having to:

- re-install Windows 8.1 to the 4TB hard disk
- re-activate Windows 8.1
- buy a third hard disk to backup personal configuration or files.

(The 4TB hard disk will be replacing the 500GB hard disk after the migration.)

Thank you.

Comment: Quite simple really. Use software to clone the drive's contents. If required use Disk Management to extend the partition on the new drive since it may show up as only 500GB after cloning.

Comment: You will want to make sure the current partition is GPT otherwise the largest partition possible on the 4TB drive will be just under 2TB. Some disk cloning software if booted as EFI media will allow you to convert a MBR image of the existing drive to a GPT partition thus allowing you to extend the main partition as its restored.